# Repeating Notifications in React Native Push Notification

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification, localnotification

How to set up react-native-push-notification to show local notification every day at particular time.

So in my mobile application I have a screen when you can set up reminders for doing something in the app and after choose 3:30 PM, I'd like to show notification on everyday at 3.30PM.

[image: set a reminder screen]

I tried to do with `PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule` but it doesn't work as expected. To test perspective let assume that I would like to show first notification at 3.30pm and in every hour show the same notification to the user.

```
PushNotification.createChannel({
    channelId: 'reminders', // (required)
    channelName: 'Task reminder notifications', // (required)
    channelDescription: 'Reminder for any tasks',
  },
  () => {},
);

PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
  channelId: 'reminders',
  title: ' Reminder!',
  message: 'You have set this reminder',
  date,
  repeatType: 'hour',
});
```

but unfortunately notification only shows at 3.30PM and repetition is not working...

I was thinking about creating an array of timestamp for whole year and run localNotificationSchedule 365 times but I don't think is a good idea...

Do you have any suggestion how should be working in iOS and android?

Answer (score 0):

Your repeatType should be "day" and not "hour".
Also, for android, you have to include the property called repeatTime. The repeatTime value is usually a number. For instance, if you select a repeatType of "day" and repeatTime of 1, you would be getting the notification every day. and if you set the repeat time to 2, it would notify you every two days.

Note, repeatTime property is only for android.